# how to locate an recently opened pdf file and save it in a target folder using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to locate an recently opened pdf file and save it in a target folder, right now i can able to locate the pdf file using its name and close it but i want to use Save As function.

Code tried to Locate and close the PDF

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" _
    Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
    ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId _
    Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long

Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Const WM_CLOSE = &H10
Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
Public Sub Test()
    Dim hWindow As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long
    Dim lProcessId As Long
    Dim lngReturnValue As Long

    hWindow = SearchHndByWndName_Parent("vieworder.pdf.php")
    hProcess = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0&, lProcessId)
    lngReturnValue = PostMessage(hWindow, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&)
End Sub
Private Function SearchHndByWndName_Parent(strSearch As String) As Long
    Dim strTMP As String * 100
    Dim nhWnd As Long
    nhWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    Do While Not nhWnd = 0
        If GetParent(nhWnd) = 0 Then
            GetWindowText nhWnd, strTMP, 100
            If InStr(strTMP, strSearch) > 0 Then
                SearchHndByWndName_Parent = nhWnd
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        nhWnd = GetWindow(nhWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)

    Loop
End Function
```

I am working in a restricted environment so I cant add any Adobe dll as reference, also the file which i am looking for is not yet saved in any folder.

Please share your suggestions.
Thank You

Comment: Will you always know the name in advance and can you explain the reason for the .PHP in "vieworder.pdf.php" ?

Comment: Yes the created file will have a constant name,  this file contains many files downloaded from website from a different pages, using VBA code i have printed those file in a cute pdf format by that all the files get merged as single document, name .php is the name format in website so while printing it has the same name.